# Python Mutliprocessing TLS socket server

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to write a multiprocessing socket server in python.

The server looks like this:

```
cert = "dummy.crt"
c = ssl.wrap_socket(conn,server_side = True, certfile = cert,         ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3  )  
t = Process(target=workerProc,args=(c))
```

It appears I cannot pass c as an args Tuple. I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'SSLSocket' object is not iterable
```

So how can I pass in the connection to the child process?

Thank you in advance.

Ranga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` takes an argument tuple, so you *can* (and should) pass `c` *inside* a tuple.

The problem in your code is that `(c)` does not create a tuple. This is done because other operations rely on parens.

`(c,)` forces the creation of a single-element tuple, which is what you want. For more details, [see this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Strange syntax. I am still getting used to python.